# ant attrib problem

Tags: ant, cruisecontrol

i am using cruisecontrol framework for nightly build.

currently i tried to set some folders to readonly = "false"

```
2011-05-18 11:40:17,089 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - C:\builds\nightly_build.xml:30: Problem: failed to create task or type attrib
2011-05-18 11:40:17,089 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.windows.Attrib was not found.
2011-05-18 11:40:17,089 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     -         This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
2011-05-18 11:40:17,105 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
2011-05-18 11:40:17,105 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     -         -C:\builds\lib
2011-05-18 11:40:17,105 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     -         -C:\Documents and Settings\admin\.ant\lib
2011-05-18 11:40:17,105 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     -         -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
2011-05-18 11:40:17,105 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - 
2011-05-18 11:40:17,105 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - Do not panic, this is a common problem.
2011-05-18 11:40:17,105 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - The commonest cause is a missing JAR.
2011-05-18 11:40:17,105 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - 
2011-05-18 11:40:17,105 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem
```

the errors are shown above.

This occurs when i use `<attrib>`:

```
<attrib readonly="false">
<dirset dir="C:/Work/6.70_Extensions/NightlyBuild" />
</attrib>
```

how do i solve this problem? and how do i find out the version of ANT that i have?

Answer (score 0):

The attrib task came with Ant 1.6 - see [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/attrib.html)
Check your Ant Version with builtin Property ant.version:

```
<echo>${ant.version}</echo>
```

Comment: hi it states ant 1.7.0 but why cant i do the `attrib`?

Comment: when using the ant version that ships with cruisecontrol you should replace with the latest Ant Version 1.8.2
if you have to use the version 1.7.0 try ant -diagnostics and get the details of your ant installation

Comment: @rebse i have a very weird situation. when i do -ant diagnostics, i get `"ant" is not recognized as an internal or external command `

Comment: oh, i see, the latest CruiseControl 2.8.3 ships with ant 1.7.0 - rather old !
see http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#ant to make your own Ant installation working with CruiseControl

Comment: when ant is not recognized, it means %ANT_HOME%/bin is not on your path; seems like you're using the version Cruisecontrol ships with

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ant-nodeps.jar in $ANT_HOME/lib? That is the jar which contains the Attrib class, so it needs to be on your Ant classpath.

Comment: echo %ANT_HOME% on windows, or call 'set' in cmd to see all your environment setting; but when using the Ant version that comes with cruisecontrol the %ANT_HOME% would be CruiseControll-InstallFolder/apache-ant-1.7.0
The CruiseControl 2.8.3 binary distribution has all of ant 1.7.0 included; when using that builtin ant version, the ant-nodeps.jar should be included !?

Comment: yes, i just checked there is `ant-nodeps.jar` in my `lib` folder under `cruisecontrol/apache-ant-1.7.0` folder

Comment: OOps, it's in the original download, i just checked, because i didn't use CruiseControl for years. So i would either redownload the CruiseControl binary = http://sourceforge.net/projects/cruisecontrol/files/CruiseControl/2.8.3/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3.zip/download or the latest Ant 1.8.2 = http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi and make it work with CruiseControl as already mentioned = http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#ant

Comment: mmpf, i read .. there is no ant-nodeps.jar ...
ok, so it seems like a CruiseControl confuiguration problem, see = http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#ant for the details - the CruiseControl community has a mailing list, i'm sure you'll get support for all your CC problems. It was a great help for me, when using CC  years before..